# Can TypeScript be configured NOT to check for Files that won't be included in the Final Output generated by Webpack?

Tags: node.js, typescript, webpack

I'm trying to resolve an Issue where TypeScript does type-checking for all Files in a Project, even if the content in the File won't be included in the Final Bundle produced by Webpack.

This gets annoying when there is a TypeScript Error reported in one of these Files, but doing the corrective action does not cause `webpack-dev-server` to reload and clear the TypeScript Error.

I understand my current `tsconfig.json` has the `include` Field set to all Files in the `src` Folder, but I would have thought that Webpack would only pass the Dependencies encountered from the Entry-Points to TypeScript.

Am I misunderstanding something? Is my configuration inadequate? Would using some other combination of TypeScript Loaders / Plugins resolve this?

Thank You :)

[Repo](https://github.com/Sean-Tay/webpack-experiments/tree/react-typescript-error)

Repo Steps:

1. `git clone`
2. `git checkout react-typescript-error`
3. `npm i`
4. `npm run dev`
5. Encounter the Type Error with `useLatestEffect` in `utils.ts`, even though `utils.ts` is not a Dependency of any File encountered from the Entry-Point.

Comment: It would not make sense to exclude these files from type checking. These files are included because they are referenced by files that are part of your application. In order to type check your application these files are needed. That they do not end up in the output is completely irrelevant

Comment: @AluanHaddad But the Error occurs in a File that isn't imported by the Entry Point File, or any of it's Dependencies - unless I'm mistaken?

Comment: then exclude `utils.ts` from your `tsconfig`.

Comment: Yep, I have the fix already. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> I understand my current tsconfig.json has the include Field set to all Files in the src Folder, but I would have thought that Webpack would only pass the Dependencies encountered from the Entry-Points to TypeScript.

Okay, so because I was using the `fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin`, [it was using TypeScript's Module Resolution behaviour](https://github.com/TypeStrong/fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin#modules-resolution), rather than waiting for the Webpack Process to pass to it the Chunk. This explains why my original line of thinking was incorrect.

My mistake was specifying `'src/**/*'` in the `'include'` Array within `tsconfig.json`. What I should have done instead was to specify only the Files that serves as Webpack's Entry Point(s) (i.e. only `index.js` in my case) for the Application in that Array.

For the purposes of this question this way resolves the original issue, but I would like to know of some way to avoid duplicating the Entry-Point specification between `tsconfig.json` and `webpack.base.config.js`.

[Repo](https://github.com/Sean-Tay/webpack-experiments/tree/react-typescript-fix)

Repo Steps:

1. `git clone`
2. `git checkout react-typescript-fix`
3. `npm i`
4. `npm run dev`
5. The Type Error with `useLatestEffect` in `utils.ts` will no longer be processed upon triggering a Build / starting the Dev Server.
6. Uncommenting the `useLatestEffect` Lines in `./src/App/RedSection/index.tsx` brings back the Error, but to be clear, that is the behavior I want.